# Unhandled System.NotImplementedException with no source available?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, notimplementedexception

I am not sure if anyone has encountered this problem.

I am developing a C# Windows Phone 8 app in VS 2012.

I have lately been getting unhandled exceptions of type System.NotImplementedException.

This is despite the fact that all of my code is surrounded in try/catch blocks, and there are no method stubs that throw a notimplementedexception.

In the output is:

*A first chance exception of the type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in MyAppName.DLL*

*An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in MyAppName.DLL and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary*

If I hit "continue" to continue debugging, I get an error message pop up dialog in VS:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll*

If I choose "Break" here, the stack trace that opens says **"No Source Available; The call stack contains only external code.  This thread is stopped with only external code frames on the call stack.** etc. etc."

This is the code highlighted after the app crashes:

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

Edit:  This is the stack:

```
Call stack with external code
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.JoltHelper.OnUnhandledException(object sender, System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.ThrowAsync.AnonymousMethod_1(object state)
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object state)
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback..System.Threading.|ThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

Comment: Do you have any custom libraries you have referenced?

Comment: Do SQLite / SQLiteAsync count?

Comment: Hey @Danny, sorry I didn't respond sooner.  Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with a similar problem, I found the apparent cause.

I had ported some code involving file input/output from a Win8 app for Surface, and, in one of the lines, neglected to change

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
```

to its corresponding

```
IsolatedStorageFile storageFolder = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
```

Somehow this was not caught in the try/catch block, but when I fixed it, the uncaught notimplementedexception no longer occurred.

Comment: Hey, a quick question. But there is an option for creating storage folders in WP8 right? As I was trying to create a folder I encountered a similar exception. Why have you changed from a storage folder to IsolatedStorageFile?